# Faster way of retrieving aggregate data from large table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that grows by tens of millions of rows each day. The rows in the table contain hourly information about page view traffic.

**The indices on the table are on url and datetime.**

I want to aggregate the information by day, rather than hourly. How should I do this? This is a query that exemplifies what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT url, sum(pageviews), sum(int_views), sum(ext_views)
FROM news
WHERE datetime >= "2012-08-29 00:00:00" AND datetime <= "2012-08-29 23:00:00"
GROUP BY url
ORDER BY pageviews DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

The above query never finishes, though. There are millions of rows in the table. Is there a more efficient way that I can get this aggregate data?

Comment: What are the indexes on the table and what is the explain plan of the query?

Comment: @Ben, the indexes are on url and datetime. What is the explain plan?

Comment: @Ben, How would I do an explicit character to date conversion? The data type of the datetime column is datetime. Does MySQL do the conversion from character to datetime type for us? I thought it did. It should be selecting 24 hours worth of data, from 0:00 to 23:59.

Comment: That's a fairly difficult question for a comment! It's an indication of the path the database optimiser will take when executing your query. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html

Comment: @egidra . . . You need to learn about partitioning tables.  This is a complex subject for an answer here.  You are reading through all the historical data unnecessarily.  With a separate partition per day, you will dramatically reduce the load of a query such as this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few points:

1. Also, as the only predicate that you're filtering on you should
   probably have an index with `datetime` as the first column.
2. You're ordering by `pageviews`. I would have assumed that you want to order by `sum(pageviews)`.
3. You're querying 23 hours of data not 24. You probably want to use an explicit less than, `<`, from midnight the next day to avoid missing anything.

```
SELECT url, sum(pageviews), sum(int_views), sum(ext_views)
  FROM news
 WHERE datetime >= '2012-08-29 00:00:00'
   AND datetime < '2012-08-30 00:00:00'
 GROUP BY url
 ORDER BY sum(pageviews) DESC
 LIMIT 10;
```

You could index this on `datetime, url, pageviews, int_views, ext_views` but I think that would be overkill; so, if the index isn't too big `datetime, url` seems like a good way to go. The only way to be certain is to *test* it and decide if any performance improvements in querying are worth the extra time taken in index maintenance.

As Gordon's just mentioned in the comments you may need to look into [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html). This enables you to query a smaller "table" that is part of the larger one. If all your queries are based at the day level it sounds like you might need to create a new one each day.

Comment: When I try to create an index on datetime, url, I get the following error: ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Comment: @Ben: Did you delete your comment re str_to_date()? I can't see it... just wondering because I don't understand why you propose that: surely those are valid [datetime literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html)?

Comment: @eggyal, yes you're right... I always prefer to explicitly convert and blinded myself.

Answer (score 6):

Tens of millions of rows *per day* is quite a lot.

Assuming:

- only 10 million new records per day;
- your table contains only the columns that you mention in your question;
- `url` is of type `TEXT` with a mean (Punycode) length of ~[77 characters](http://www.supermind.org/blog/740/average-length-of-a-url-part-2);
- `pageviews` is of type `INT`;
- `int_views` is of type `INT`;
- `ext_views` is of type `INT`; and
- `datetime` is of type `DATETIME`

then each day's data will occupy around 9.9 × 10<sup>8</sup> bytes, which is almost 1GiB/day.  In reality it may be considerably more, because the above assumptions were quite conservative.

MySQL's [maximum table size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/table-size-limit.html) is determined, amongst other things, by the underlying filesystem on which its data files reside. If you're using the MyISAM engine (as suggested by your comment beneath) without partitioning on Windows or Linux, then a limit of a few GiB is not uncommon; which implies the table will reach its capacity well within a working week!

As [@Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205185/faster-way-of-retrieving-aggregate-data-from-large-table#comment16347655_12205185) mentioned, you should [partition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning.html) your table; However, each table has a [limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning-limitations.html#partitioning-limitations-max-partitions) of 1024 partitions.  With 1 partition/day (which would be imminently sensible in your case), you will be limited to storing under 3 years of data in a single table before the partitions start getting reused.

I would therefore advise that you keep each year's data in its own table, each partitioned by day.  Furthermore, as [@Ben explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12205569/623041), a composite index on `(datetime, url)` would help (I actually propose creating a `date` column from `DATE(datetime)` and indexing that, because it will enable MySQL to [prune](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning-pruning.html) the partitions when performing your query); and, if row-level locking and transactional integrity are not important to you (for a table of this sort, they may not be), using MyISAM may not be daft:

```
CREATE TABLE news_2012 (
  INDEX (date, url(100))
)
Engine = MyISAM
PARTITION BY HASH(TO_DAYS(date)) PARTITIONS 366
SELECT *, DATE(datetime) AS date FROM news WHERE YEAR(datetime) = 2012;

CREATE TRIGGER news_2012_insert BEFORE INSERT ON news_2012 FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.date = DATE(NEW.datetime);

CREATE TRIGGER news_2012_update BEFORE UPDATE ON news_2012 FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.date = DATE(NEW.datetime);
```

If you choose to use MyISAM, you can not only archive completed years (using [*`myisampack`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/myisampack.html)) but can also replace your original table with a [`MERGE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/merge-storage-engine.html) one comprising the `UNION` of all of your underlying year tables (an alternative that would also work in InnoDB would be to create a [`VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/views.html), but it would only be useful for `SELECT` statements as `UNION` views are neither updatable nor insertable):

```
DROP TABLE news;
CREATE TABLE news (
  date DATE,
  INDEX (date, url(100))
)
Engine = MERGE
INSERT_METHOD = FIRST
UNION = (news_2012, news_2011, ...)
SELECT * FROM news_2012 WHERE FALSE;
```

You can then run your above query (along with any other) on this merge table:

```
SELECT   url, SUM(pageviews), SUM(int_views), SUM(ext_views)
FROM     news
WHERE    date = '2012-08-29'
GROUP BY url
ORDER BY SUM(pageviews) DESC
LIMIT    10;
```

Comment: I will start with the most obvious optimization, creating an index on datetime,url. When I try to create the index, I get the following error: ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Comment: @egidra: Suggest you specify a prefix length for `url`--e.g. `INDEX(datetime, url(100))`, with which I have updated my answer above--the actual length you should choose will depend on your data: how many characters of the `url` column does one need to read in order to filter the table to a relatively small number of records?

Comment: Not that many, probably 100 characters will distinguish the urls from each other.